# Query two sections filtered by different custom fields, then order them

Tags: entries, array, order, merge, sort

Two channels:
1) exhibitions, which have a startDate and EndDate
2) events, which have a date

I need to grab the current exhibitions, future exhibitions and future events, which I do using this:

```
{% set allOccurrences = craft.entries.section('exhibitions').startDate('<= ' ~ now | date("U")).endDate('>= ' ~ now | date("U"))
    | merge(craft.entries.section('exhibitions').startDate('> ' ~ now | date("U")))
    | merge(craft.entries.section('events').date('>= ' ~ now | date("U"))) %}
```

Now what I need to do is order them, by the startDate (if an exhibition) and the date (if an event). In other words, having already fetched the entries, I need to order them by two different fields.

I'm not sure this is possible without a plugin - could anyone give me any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's this super useful [SuperSort](https://topshelfcraft.com/lagniappe/supersort) plugin that would make this possible.

```
{% set sortAsTemplate = '{{ object.section == "Exhibitions" ? object.startDate|date("U") : object.date|date("U") }}' %}
{% set sortedOccurrences = allOccurrences|supersort('sortAs', sortAsTemplate) %}
```

Comment: Any idea why this returns "Unexpected "allOccurrences" tag"?

Comment: Removed the error using:
{% set sortedOccurrences = allOccurrences | supersort('sortAs', sortAsTemplate) %}

Comment: Wasn't sorting properly, though, but this fixed it:
{% set sortAsTemplate = '{{ object.startDate | length ? object.startDate|date("U") : object.date|date("U") }}' %}